# A modification of a cyclic group that seems to break being a group. What is it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

**Background:** I came up with this trying to answer an actually silly question of "when can
$1+1=3$ be true" ?

---

Consider a set $\mathcal S = \{0,\cdots, N-1\}$
coupled with an operation "+" that takes any pair of elements $a,b\in\mathcal S$

$$a+b \to \text{mod}(N-\text{mod}(a+b,N),N)$$

In other words like a cyclic group **but** after the rotation a reflection is carried out.

My question is: can we classify what I have constructed?

If we analyze the group axioms

1. Closure is trivial to prove.
2. Inverse element is easy to assign, for $s$ just pick $N-s$, the rotation takes us to $0$ and the subsequent reflection does not move $0$ anywhere.
3. Identity element is much trickier. $0+0 = 0$, but for any $s+0$, this will not be $s$.

However, applied **twice**, it will act as identity $s+0+0 = s$ as we will reflect back again.

So in the language of abstract algebra, what have I done!?

Comment: There is one actual group where "$1+1=3$": the trivial group $\{0\}$, where $0=1=3$.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, but is it possible to find a non-trivial one?

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10154032), it's not clear to me what it means to ask whether $1 + 1 = 3$ in a group; a group is required to have an identity element, which you denote by $0$ because you are working additively, but a group (as opposed to a ring) need not contain an extra element called $1$.  If $1$ is *any* element of a group such that $1 + 1 = 3$, where we define $3 = (1 + 1) + 1$, then adding $-(1 + 1)$ to each side of the equation $1 + 1 = (1 + 1) + 1$, and using associativity, gives $1 = 0$. […](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10154382)

Comment: […](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10154380)  If you meant to ask for a *ring* (with multiplicative identity $1$ in addition to the additive identity $0$) where $1 + 1 = 3$, then thinking of the ring as an additive group gives that $1 = 0$ just as above, and then, for every element $x$ of the ring, we have that $x = 1x = 0x = 0$, so that the ring is trivial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will let $a\oplus b $ denote $N-\text{mod}(a+b,N)$. This operation is not even associative, as $$(s\oplus0)\oplus0=s\ne N-s=s\oplus0=s\oplus(0\oplus0)$$
Actually, it is a commutative [quasigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup), which is a magma with the Latin square property. Let's check the axioms:

1. Closure and commutativity: trivial
2. For each $a,b\in S$, take $x=y=a\oplus b=N-\text{mod}(a+b,N)$, then
   $$a\oplus x=a\oplus (a\oplus b)=a\oplus (\text{mod}(N-a-b,N))=N-\text{mod}(N-b,N)=b$$
   $$y\oplus a=(a\oplus b) \oplus a =a\oplus (a\oplus b)=b$$

By the way, $N-x$ is not the inverse of $x$, because $0$ is not an identity.

Comment: Aha. Quasigroup! I was not aware of this concept. Thank you. Is the latin square property guaranteeing unique divisibility?

Comment: Yes, $x$ and $y$ in the second axiom are always unique.

Comment: Aha an identity element must exist for inverse to be defined, not just that there exist pairs of element that all go to some unique element. 

Is there some other name in abstract algebra for the weaker situation we have here : an element which we can find pairs which take all other elements to it but does not leave elements unchanged if operating with them alone?

Comment: Both in a group, and in the algebraic structure we've got here, *every* element will have that property. Suppose I decide to think of an arbitrary element $x$ as the identity. Then for any $a$, if we let $a' = x \oplus a$, then we have $a \oplus a' = a' \oplus a = x$. (Relatedly, $0$ is not unique in the property that $(a \oplus 0) \oplus 0 = a$ for all $a$; we have $(a \oplus b) \oplus b = a$ for all $a$ and $b$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hmm.. Yes, you are right, but 0 takes 0 to itself. I think no other element does that in addition to the property mentioned?

Comment: Well, not in general, but when $N$ is a multiple of $3$, $N/3$ and $2N3/$ will also have that property.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems with your construction : first of all, it doesn't seem to be well defined over S, you would have to include N (else, if you compute 1*(N-1), you get N).

If you would like to compare this operation with that coming from a group law, it seems to me that the first property that you should look for is associativity (before anything else). It doesn't seem to ever hold here ; an explicit counter-example when N=4 is given by (I will use the symbol * to denote your operation)

(1*1)*2 = 2*2 = 4 but 1*(1*2) = 1*1 = 2.

It does seem like a fun operation and perhaps it would be possible to 'measure' how far this operation is from being associative (for instance, what happens if you compute x*(y*z)-(x*y)*z ?). Hope this helps !

Comment: You are right, I added an extra modulus to account for that.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Your construction $x(y z) - (x y)z$ involves two binary operations where a group has only one, so it doesn't make sense in the setting of a general group; but, for a ring, it is called the [associator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associator).